# Execute POST request from Alpine container

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I want to execute a `POST` request with custom headers over HTTPS from a pod in our kubernetes cluster, which is running openjdk11-jre with alpine as base image (`adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:jre-11.0.11_9-alpine` to be exact).

With this image `curl` or `wget` are not available and `nc` doesn't support HTTPS. I already tried to achieve something with `jrunscript` which comes with the jre but was only able to send a `GET` with `cat('https://example.com')`.

Of course one way would be to copy an executable or a compiled Java class into the pod, over which I could send the request but I'd prefer a one-liner that is ready to go.

Comment: So go through what *is* installed in your container (we cannot know this), and see if you can use anything for HTTPS. E.g. is `openssl` available? Then you can do `openssl s_client`. Etc. Otherwise you need some Java.

Comment: Our image just has a `jar` file copied into it. So it's just the plain Alpine image with a JRE (just added the versions). I currently didn't find any program that would fit but often people here find clever ways to utilize existing programs for some command line magic :)

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that there is a `busybox` binary in the Alpine image which contains a stripped-down version of `wget`. Unfortunately it does not allow to send `PUT` or `DELETE` requests but for `POST` this worked:

```
wget -qO - --post-data '' --header 'MyHeader: 123' https://example.com/
```

Or alternatively if there is no `wget` link to `busybox`

```
busybox wget -qO - --post-data '' --header 'MyHeader: 123' https://example.com/
```